# Why does this equal true

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So let's say we have the following code,

```
var attachRed = false;
```

Why does

```
attachRed = !attachRed equals true?
```

I'm asking because i have the following Vue code and i don't understand why it works

```
<div id="app">
  <div 
    class="demo" 
    @click="attachRed = !attachRed"
    :class="{red: attachRed}">
  </div>
</div?

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
  data: {
    attachRed: false
  }
})
```

Comment: Single `=` does not compare values but assigns them. If you want to compare `attachRed` use `==` or even `===`

Answer (score 3):

In JS, as well as in most of programming languages, single "=" operator is used to assign one value to another. Thus, doing `attachRed = !attachRed` you're simply reassigning the value of `attachRed`. When you reassign the value of any variable, the return is *new value*. If you want to compare two values, use either `==` or `===`.

Answer (score 2):

The `!` operator means "not". So if the value of `attachRed` is `true`, then `!attachRed` means "not true" (which of course means "false"). If the value of `attachRed` is `false`, then `!attachRed` means "not false" – so, "true".

Comment: The OP isn't actually trying to do a comparison. The click handler is supposed to toggle `attachRed`.